# How i alter this task in this program?

Tags: python

I need to make program that which will input one student’s coursework mark and prelim mark and calculate and display their percentage and grade.

`(Grade = ((coursework mark + prelim mark) *100) / 150)`

and Alter the program so that it will read the name, coursework mark and prelim mark for all the 15 students in your class from an external file (available from your assessor). and to enable it to find out how many “A” passes are in the class by using the “Count Occurrences” standard algorithm.

- A. Grade is awarded for greater than or equal to 70%
- B. Grade is awarded to those between 60% and 69%
- C Grade is awarded to those between 50% and 59%
- D Grade is awarded to those between 45% and 49%
- No Grade is awarded to those under 45%

and last to find out who has the best percentage in the class by using the “Find Max” standard algorithm.

this is my code:

```py
marks={59,33,55,10,47,60,57,45,20,39,55,25,23,30,54}

prelim={75,80,88,45,78,90,82,65,40,59,75,50,48,60,86}

name={Kevin,Anna,Paul,John,Anne,Frank,Susan,Mary,James,Katie,Mark,Stacey,Michael,Abdul,Kirsty}

def calculate():
  
  grade= ((marks[x] + prelim[x]) * 100 / 150)

  return 
    
for x in range (14):
  
  names= str(name[x])
  
  print( name, "has achieve", calculate, "percentage")
```

Comment: Thank you for posting your code. Have you tried running it? Does it output what you want to see?

Comment: yes, however it does not work

Comment: also, unfortunately, i don't understand how to do the other tasks

Comment: it would be great if you help

Comment: Ok, so `however it does not work` is not a description of the symptoms. What exactly is wrong? Is to do with the fact that you never call the `calculate()` function?

Comment: it would be simpler to get `grade` directly in `for`-loop without creating function `calculuate()`

Comment: my first target is to input one student’s coursework mark and prelim mark and calculate and display their percentage and grade.

Comment: unfortunately, I'm still getting an error

Comment: @furas: I would prefer a beginner to create functions, even unnecessary ones, as they are a point at which the program can better describe itself to future readers. Functions once written can be easily renamed to better names, or in the end inlined to simplify the code.

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you will get a `NameError` because your student names are not in quotation marks. Secondly, accessing set or dictionary values in the way that you are doing is invalid. Change the set to a list or change the set to a dictionary and access the keys of the dictionary with dict.keys(). Updated code:

```
marks=[59,33,55,10,47,60,57,45,20,39,55,25,23,30,54]

prelim=[75,80,88,45,78,90,82,65,40,59,75,50,48,60,86]

name=["Kevin","Anna", "Paul","John","Anne","Frank","Susan","Mary","James","Katie","Mark","Stacey","Michael","Abdul","Kirsty"]

def calculate(index):
  return ((marks[index] + prelim[index]) * 100 / 150)

for x in range(14):
  names = name[x]
  print(names, "has achieve", calculate(x), "percentage")
```